# BLE Beacon Temperature

Tags: beacon, temperature

I have a Bluetooth beacon which emits temperature and humidity. I have created an android application which is able to receive data from the beacon such as ID, Address etc.

But it's not showing showing the temperature value. How to do it?
Do I need to add any extra methods, functions, variables?

The code is attached below. Thanks in advance

```
tx1.setText("ID1:"+beacon.getId1());
                tx2.setText("ID2: "+beacon.getId2());
                tx3.setText("ID3: "+beacon.getId3());
                tx5.setText("BLE Addr: "+beacon.getBluetoothAddress());
                tx6.setText("Distance: "+beacon.getDistance());
                tx7.setText("Manufacturer: "+beacon.getManufacturer());
                tx8.setText(""+beacon.getDataFields());
                Log.d("beacon123",""+beacon.getDataFields());
                String b= String.valueOf(beacon.getDataFields());
                Toast toastt = Toast.makeText(context,"" +b, duration);
                toastt.show();
```

i am reading the beacon through an nRF android application which is showing the following data

[ID data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLDB.png)

[Manufacturer id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5CnH.png)
[Temperature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANlag.png)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a number of issues here.

- The method `beacon.getDataFields()` returns an array.  Try getting the first data field with  `beacon.getDataFields().get(0)`
- Make sure your beacon either supports the AltBeacon format and has the temperature encoded in the last byte of the transmission, or you are creating a BeaconParser with the format of your beacon.
- If using an Eddystone format, you will need to make sure telemetry is on, a BeaconParser is set  up for Eddystone-TLM, then access temperature from `g etExtraDataFields()`

Comment: i tried the beacon.getDatafields().get(0) method,but kept getting the o/p as 0

Comment: for the last point i added the Eddystone-TLM beacon parser,and checked with the getExtraField methods, but same as before,no luck!

Comment: Can you please update your question with the beacon manufacturer and beacon format (AltBeacon, Eddystone, etc.). Does the documentation say it supports advertising temperature?  If so, does it say how it does so? This is not a standard feature so there are many ways of doing it.

Comment: i tired all the beacon formats, kept getting null.Finally i tired with iBeacon format and got data such as Id1,Id2,Id3,Bluetooth address

Comment: only issue is to find out the temperature data from the beacon

Comment: The iBeacon format has no data fields, so unless the hardware manufacturer encodes temperature in major (id2) or minor (id3) that format simply won't work to transfer the data.  You really need to get their documentation.

Comment: i found out that its a nordic semiconductor Ble beacon, so any idea where to go from there?

Comment: Nordic Semiconductor makes Bluetooth SoCs, not finished beacons.  Each Nordic chipset can be customized with different firmware that enables the features you describe (beacon transmission of temperature).  You will need to get the documentation for the beacon firmware put on the Nordic chip to be able to figure out how to do what you want.

Comment: what should be added as the telemetry or the access the telemetry for the eddystone tlm beacon

Comment: just need to access the temperature of the eddystone tlm beacon, i am using an android app called  Beacon Stimulator, i am able to detect all types of beacon except the eddystone TLM

Comment: i saw your answer regarding the telemetry access, i added the code but it still not showing anything, only need for the eddystone TLM

Comment: Try my BeaconScope app in the PlayStore.  It is based on the same library.  If it does not show TLM with temp, then that means the beacon is not transmitting it.

Comment: i tried it with nRF beacon app, it showing temperature and humidity in text(UTF-8) format,the t&h data is attached with manufactured data.But it only shows in that particular application.

Comment: I tried with your BeaconScope app and for stimulation i used BeaconStimulator app.I tried with all beacon layouts and it was displaying all except for the Eddystone TLM beacon,not showing anything about it.

Comment: I did the same with the nRF application and in that application its showing the temperature. i guess only the nRF library has support for temperature and not any other library.i am not getting the nRF library anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you see in nRF?  I suspect this may be a GATT characteristic hosting the temperature and not part of a beacon advertisement.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i have attached the temperature and humidity screenshots

Comment: That screenshot is super helpful.  It suggests that the temperature and humidity are encoded as text bytes in the advertisement itself.  On that screenshot, there is a link to "Show Raw"  can you try tapping that and attaching another screenshot of it?  If so, I think I can share code needed to parse the temperature and humidity with the Android Beacon Library.

Comment: i have attached all the data i could get from the device,only in this app.